# could you suggest me to create a plugin for web application to calculate the each and every method execution time

Tags: java

I want to calculate the each and every method execution time like profiler do..  for my web application. IDE is netbeans and application server is glassfishV2. 
my application file is EAR (ejb+war). could any body suggest me on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options I would like to suggest is JAMon (http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) for monitoring application and method execution times.

It provides

- an easy to hook interface,
- can be used to monitor methods, sql queries and much more
- provides capability to dynamically be turned on and off in production environments
- provides nice statistics UI.
- and much more ... detailed Features @ http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/#Introduction

Comment: Hi Jayendra, Could you tell me the configuration details about this JAMon because In that site which you mentioned above didnot mention the configuration details. If please provide those details it could be better.

Comment: Depends upon what framework you are using. The JaMon docs provide a simple solution with filter http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/#ServletFilter. With Spring you can easily hook an aspect.

Comment: that JAMon servlet only for servlets, jsp's,jpeg right, but how to calculate the methods execution time. we are using JSF framework. thank you.

Comment: http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/#SimpleExamples . you can use monitor start/stop to monitor methods. You can use aspect so that these start/stop are fired before and after the methods and generate statistics for all.

Comment: thank you. I have a doubt. calculating method execution should be generic. with this approach can i achieve this? and if so that logic should catch the each and every method call in application. is it possible?

Comment: yes ... aspect can help you to hook this to methods making it generic and you do not need to hand code it. You can check for its integration in JSF. for example in spring this can be applied using http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html

Comment: If you dont mind could you explain programatically i have been working on this for the past 10 days

Comment: public class PerformanceMonitorIncptr implements MethodInterceptor{
   
    public PerformanceMonitorIncptr() {
    }public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        String mName = mi.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." + mi.
                getMethod().getName();

Comment: Object returnValue = null;
        try {
            returnValue = mi.proceed();
        } finally {
            mon.stop();
            System.out.println(mon);
        }
        System.out.println(mName);
//        System.out.println(l - System.currentTimeMillis());
        return returnValue;

    }
}

Comment: I confused a little bit that how to configure this because for every method invocation it should be invoked and it should calculate the time for that how to configure it i am using JSF framework

Comment: let me check if i can find an example or solution for you.

Comment: hi jayendra i configured the AspectJ in my application now I am getting the result thanks for your valuable suggestions.